# Regex for parsing blocks of file

Tags: python, regex

I have a file formatted:

```
BEGIN
   xxx
END;
BEGIN
   xxx
EXCEPTION
   xxx
END;
BEGIN
   xxx
EXCEPTION
   xxx
END;
```

What i need is only the data between only BEGIN and EXCEPTION block and ignore the BEGIN-END and EXCEPTION-END block. I have created a regex but its not giving me the desired output:

```
body=re.findall(r'BEGIN.*^[^BEGIN].*EXCEPTION', data, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
```

Also I want to remove the BEGIN and EXCEPTION from the output, can I do it through regex. 
Alternatively I can use replace function too.
Pls help.

Comment: Something like [`(?m)^BEGIN(?:\n(?!BEGIN$).*)*\nEXCEPTION$`](https://regex101.com/r/RWtnBz/4)? You cannot use `re.DOTALL` with this "unrolled" expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this Regex:

```
BEGIN(?:(?!END)[\s\S])*EXCEPTION
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UuQSCA/1)

OR

```
(?<=BEGIN)(?:(?!END)[\s\S])*(?=EXCEPTION)
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UuQSCA/2)

**Explanation(1st Regex):**

- `BEGIN` - matches `BEGIN`
- `(?:(?!END)[\s\S])*` - [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/5331061) to match 0+ occurrences of any character that does not start with `END`
- `EXCEPTION` - matches `EXCEPTION`

Comment: @Sarthak
 [They work to some extent](https://regex101.com/r/sD1fTZ/1) only.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for pointing that out. Would this work [`BEGIN(?:(?!\bEND\b)[\s\S])*EXCEPTION`](https://regex101.com/r/sD1fTZ/2) in that case?

Comment: @Gurman Probably. If there are no string literals or comments inside with `END`. That is why I anchored BEGIN and END at line start/end.